# Catalina.stop: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, shell, tomcat

i have fresh installed tomcat8 on my server. When i call this command ./catalina.sh stop in the /bin folder, i receive this error:

```
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60
    Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Dec 12, 2015 5:33:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
    SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
    Dec 12, 2015 5:33:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
    SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

same thing with startup.sh. I already checked the port and it is free. i installed tomcat 8 new but i get the same errors.

Comment: Has Tomcat started up fully before you run the stop command? Can you hit port 8080 from a browser?

Comment: yeah, and check your iptables in case firewall is blocking the ports

Comment: i don't have any firewall and i can't run tomcat from the browser.